# Is double password protection safe for admin authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, authorization

I was looking at some of my past codes, and I viewed one of my admin boards I've made. I had it setup so that the admin has to define/enter 2 passwords for his account.
Is this really double-safe or was I deluded?
It seems that it's reaaally hard to force-match username and 2 passwords from the client side. I've got it limited to 100 tries, dogh...

Comment: Let's put it this way: what's the difference between requiring two passwords and requiring one password with double the length?

Comment: Haha you're right... Didn't think of it that way.

closed as STUPID QUESTION

lol

Comment: I don't think it's a stupid question. Also: if the two passwords are always required and effectively act as one, then it's needlessly complicated. If they actually have different effects (for example one for "normal" operations, both for "risky" operations), then it might actually be worth looking into (but I'd consider other, stronger security mechanisms anyway).

Comment: Double authentication can be good but not if always standard. I need a login and password to login to my bank account, but whenever I want to do a financial transaction I need an aditional unique authnetication number.

Comment: Questions about best practice related to security are a much better fit for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is refered to as [Wish-it-was](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WishItWas-TwoFactor-.aspx) two-factor authentication. There's some interesting ideas in the realm of cheap two-factor auth at [this](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=77) blog post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are the major risks related to passwords?

1. The password is not secure enough. This makes it easy, for example, to brute force a password, or simply guess it.
2. Wrong hashing techniques are used or there is no hashing at all. It makes it easy for anyone who have (think programmers, DBAs, sysadmins) or can get (think SQL Injection) access to the database to do whatever he wants with the passwords of every user.
3. Man in the middle attacks, such as in the scenarios where there is no SSL and the machine connects through an unsafe network, such as wifi, make it easy to get the plain text passwords.
4. Finally, password theft can involve some techniques such as social engineering, as well as be as basic as spotting a password written on a post-it.
5. Lack of proper password reset policy. Working as a freelancer, I often receive root (yes, root) access passwords from my customers. Sadly, years later, those passwords would probably still work, despite the fact that there were dozen of other developers who have received the same password.

None are solved by using two passwords instead of one. Instead, forcing to have two passwords instead of one may have some negative effects:

- It encourages the users to use weak passwords or to have two similar passwords,
- Otherwise, chances are the passwords will be found on a post-it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not uncommon.

Forgetting the fact that you are talking about you admin account for a second, it is typical for banks to require multiple passwords for users, often a password and some kind of pin number.

They often augment this with a number of security questions as well that you will be prompted to answer 1 of.

That being said for forum software that kind of thing might be overkill for a normal user.

Comment: When you talk about US banks, you have to remember that US banks are bound to [following a law which requires "two factor authentication" but doesn't define what kind of factors](http://www.ffiec.gov/pdf/authentication_guidance.pdf). The motivation behind the implementations is complying with that law with a minimum of extra cost and user annoyance, not actually improving the security. When your motivation is security, you shouldn't use it as an example.

Comment: Also, I think banks should rather be used as an example of what one shouldn't do in terms of security, not the opposite. Personally, one of the weakest account I have is the account of my bank's website.

Comment: @Philipp I'm in the UK not the US, there may be some similar law here. I take both points. All I was saying was the it is not uncommon so don't beat yourself up about it. Totally agree with all of MainMa 's post